# Run multiple tweens with one common ease function (GSAP)

Tags: javascript, animation, timeline, gsap

Can I combine multiple tweens and run them with one ease function? Something like this:

```
var el = $('#some-element');

var tw1 = new TweenMax.to(el, 1, {left: 100});
var tw2 = new TweenMax.to(el, 1, {left: 200});
var tw3 = new TweenMax.to(el, 1, {left: 300});

var tl = new TimelineMax({ease:Power2.easeOut})
    .add(tw1)
    .add(tw2)
    .add(tw3);
```

I've made sandbox example for this issue: http://codepen.io/panych/pen/qpjCK
So how to make move the box with common easing?

**UPD**

New sandboxes:

1. http://codepen.io/panych/pen/qpjCK
2. http://codepen.io/panych/pen/aLHGy

We need to make to move the box from the first example with one common easing function, as it has been shown in the second example, but without removing middle tweens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to do it is tweening the timeline's [progress value](http://api.greensock.com/js/com/greensock/core/Animation.html#progress%28%29), like this:

```js
var el = $('#some-element');

var tw1 = new TweenMax.to(el, 1, {left: 100});
var tw2 = new TweenMax.to(el, 1, {left: 200});
var tw3 = new TweenMax.to(el, 1, {left: 300});

var tl = new TimelineMax()
.add(tw1)
.add(tw2)
.add(tw3);

TweenLite.to(tl, tl.duration, {progress:1, ease:Power2.easeOut});
```

Also the [add() method](http://api.greensock.com/js/com/greensock/TimelineLite.html#add%28%29) allows you to add an array of tweens and then pass the alignment as a string, like this:

```js
var el = $('#some-element');

var tw1 = new TweenMax.to(el, 1, {left: 100});
var tw2 = new TweenMax.to(el, 1, {left: 200});
var tw3 = new TweenMax.to(el, 1, {left: 300});

var tl = new TimelineMax()
.add([tw1,tw2,tw3], 'sequence');
```

Like that the tweens in the array play one after the other.

Also you can tween the time property of the timeline like Jamie Jefferson illustrated in this codepen:

http://codepen.io/jamiejefferson/pen/zsEAt

Take a look at the add() method which has an amazing range of uses.

Rodrigo.

EDIT: I forgot to add the position parameter in the add() method. This method accepts a position parameter and an alignment parameter, and since both are strings it's mandatory to include both.

So the code looks like this:

```js
var el = $('#some-element');

var tw1 = new TweenMax.to(el, 1, {left: 100});
var tw2 = new TweenMax.to(el, 1, {left: 200});
var tw3 = new TweenMax.to(el, 1, {left: 300});

var tl = new TimelineMax()
.add([tw1,tw2,tw3], '+=0', 'sequence');
```

With the +=0, we're telling GSAP to include all those elements, in sequence, at the end of the timeline.

Comment: For me, only Jamie's Jefferson's solution works. Here is the pen which demonstrates that a case-control `div#A` with only 1 tween is in sync with another `div#B` which have 3 tweens: http://codepen.io/abernier/pen/ONRwoO

Comment: @abernier Ah, yes you're right. I forgot to add the position parameter, since position and alignment are strings it's rather difficult codewise, to make a difference between them. I changed the code and it should work properly now.

Answer (score 0):

Use only one tween (the final destination) and if pass through points are required use the  BezierPlugin to add them.

http://api.greensock.com/js/com/greensock/plugins/BezierPlugin.html#bezierThrough();

Comment: I nee to use more then one tween. Let's say I need to animate different properties, but with ONE common ease function. I need to combine them into one tween, and then apply ease, as suppose.